# Build Xamarin.ios for production via command line on MacOS

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin

i'm trying to compile a "release" package of my xamarin.iOS app via command line
i've tried what Microsoft suggest here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support

But it talks about itunes and simulator, never about the sign of the package

i need an IPA that can be uploaded via Transporter app on my developer account and can be sent for review, how can i achieve it?

the other thing i'm trying to understand is how the whole process works
if i want change the bundle identifier to create another app (from the same code but with different resources), all i need to do is to change the info.plis and entitlement.plist?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and try to be more specific in areas like "it talks about itunes", try to exactly specify something you experimented with or add exact error or other messages you see. Perhaps try to split your question into two?

Answer (score 2):

In order to produce a IPA package you need to set the following MSBuild properties when building:

- BuildIpa - set this to true to produce a IPA
- IpaPackageDir - set this to where you want the IPA to be output
- IpaPackageName - the name of the IPA file
- Platform - set this to iPhone to make an IPA that runs on iPhone
- Configuration - set this to the build configuration you want to use. Usually either Release or Ad-Hoc

Using this and setting the target to Build you can simply run MSBuild to produce this for you.

```
msbuild my-ios-app.csproj /p:BuildIpa=True /p:IpaPackageDir=path/to/output /p:IpaPackageName=my-ios-app-name.ipa /p:Platform=iPhone /p:Configuration=Release /t:Build
```

This will produce an IPA for you which is signed with the provisioning profile and signing certificate set for the given configuration in the project properties.

As for your second question. Then yes, the Info.plist dictates the the name and identifier of the App. Not so much the entitlements.plist.

Comment: Hi, really, really ty for your help

But if i want to change the provisioning? Is there a way to indicate it via command line? Or it isn't necessary?
I mean, i have 2 or plus apps based on the same code (but with different resources, colors and "base configuration" as i said earlier) i can use the same provisioning file? Or not?
for "two different apps" i mean that on the app store they are literally 2 different apps, only the base code is the same, differences are about functionalities and resources such as images or logos, some are enabled, some not

Comment: Usually you would have your CI only install the relevant provisioning profiles and signing certificates and set everything to auto in the project properties.

Comment: The correct provisioning profile should get automatically picked up based on the bundle identifier in the Info.plist